# How to expand div to cover remaining page height

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, height

Sorry, searching has returned tons of results, but nothing that matches my problem exactly. Seems like SO is drowning in div-height problems. :-(

I have the following test layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Div Test</title>
    <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        body {
            margin:0;
        }
        div {
            width:100%;
        }
        .content {
            position:relative;
            float:none;
            margin-left:auto;
            margin-right:auto;
            display:block;
            width:680px;
        }
        #one {
            height:100px;
            position:relative;
            background-color:#0000FF;
        }
        #two {
            position:relative;
            background-color:#00FF00;
            height:100%;
            min-height:400px;
        }
        #three {
            height:70px;
            background-color:#FF0000;
            bottom:0;
            position:absolute;
        }
        #oneone {
            height:100%;
            background-color:#838383;
        }
        #twotwo {
            height:400px;
            background-color:#EEFF47;
        }
        #threethree {
            height:100%;
            background-color:#400080;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="one">
        <div class="content" id="oneone"></div>
    </div>
    <div id="two">
        <div class="content" id="twotwo">Expand this to the bottom.</div>
    </div>
    <div id="three">
        <div class="content" id="threethree"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want the div one and three to stay in top and bottom, div twotwo should expand in height to accommodate my pagecontent, and expand when the content is more than the page height, therefore pushing the div three down and cause scrolling.

Is this possible without JavaScript? If so, what's the CSS solution to this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Javascript is needed for this. When you have a header and footer height and you want the middle to have 100% height, the result will be full page height + header height + footer height. So you'll end up with scroll bars to view the entire page. If you want everything to fit in the same window, then you we need to use javascript to detect how much middle space is left and assign height accordingly.

To detect middle height with jQuery, you can do

```
var one = $('#one').height(),
three = $('#three').height(),
two = parseInt($(window).height() - three - one);
alert(two);
```

This will give you the height that is left for the middle part which is `<div id="two">` in your case.

See jQuery code in action at http://jsfiddle.net/Ppw5y/. Notice that when you expand the window and you run the code again, you will have a different content height.

Comment: Interesting. I guess it can't be done with CSS. If I set the result as the min-height, it would expand once content is longer than the height required to fill the page, right?

Comment: Another thought: Wouldn't CSS3 media queries be able to dynamically adapt to the page height? Or is that JS trickery as well?

Comment: @jon CSS3 is not cross browser compatible.

Comment: Sorry, this does not work in Chrome. Scrolling is broken, as is sizing on larger monitors.

Answer (score 0):

How about setting height:auto; for #two and #twotwo?

Comment: Doesn't work, the div is only as high as the content. I want to have it fill the space between the two divs.

Answer (score 0):

I think it can be done without script. Check this code out.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Div Test</title>
<style type="text/css" media="screen">
    body {
        margin:0;
    }
    div {
        width:100%;
    }
    .content {
        position:relative;
        float:none;
        margin-left:auto;
        margin-right:auto;
        display:block;
        width:680px;
    }
    #one {
        height:100px;
        position:relative;
        background-color:#0000FF;
    }
    #two {
        position:relative;
        background-color:#00FF00;
        /*changed*/
        min-height:400px;
    }
    #three {
        height:70px;
        background-color:#FF0000;
        bottom:0;
        position:relative; /*changed*/
    }
    #oneone {
        height:100%;
        background-color:#838383;
    }
    #twotwo {
        /*changed*/
        min-height:400px;/*changed*/
        background-color:#EEFF47;
    }
    #threethree {
        height:100%;
        background-color:#400080;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="one">
    <div class="content" id="oneone"></div>
</div>
<div id="two">
    <div class="content" id="twotwo">Expand this to the bottom.</div>
</div>
<div id="three">
    <div class="content" id="threethree"></div>
</div>    
</body>
</html>
```

I have added a /* changed */ wherever i have changed your code.

Comment: No, sorry, this isn't working, the footer is no longer at the bottom of the window. Not it, thanks anyway!