# How to resize content area with CSS dynamically and no javascript

Tags: html, css

I want is this:

- the blue area resizes with when the browser window resizes.
- The header is visible.
- the blue area starts where the header finishes (not behind the header or above).
- the blue area ends before the footer.
- between the blue area and the footer exist 5 yellow pixels.

Is this possible only with CSS and HTML ( without any javascript ) ?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-US">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Test</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width; initial-scale=1.0; maximum-scale=1.0;"/>
    <style>

    *{
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
    }

    header, nav, article, footer, address {  
        display: block;  
    }

    header{
        position:relative; height: 50px; background-color:#2b2b2b;
    }

    footer{
        height: 50px; 
        width:100%; 
        bottom: 0px; 
        position: fixed; 
        background: red;
    }

    #explorer{
        position:relative; bottom:55px; 
    }

    #sections{
        width: 100%; height: 100%; bottom: 55px; position:fixed; background: blue;
    }

    </style>
</head>

<body style="background-color:yellow">
    <header >
        <h1>Test</h1>
    </header>
  <div id="explorer" >
      <div id="sections" >
   &nbsp;
      </div>
  </div>
  <footer>
       /* Footer Content */
  </footer>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Check out CSS media queries... I know it can change when window sizes change.

Comment: I just answered a similar question at [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5047532/how-to-expand-div-to-cover-rest-of-page-height/5048072#5048072](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5047532/how-to-expand-div-to-cover-rest-of-page-height/5048072#5048072)

Comment: @Peter - Thanks for the tip, but it doesn't solve this problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think Kit's code needs just one adjustment & that is we have to remove the height:100% from the *sections* div & it will work just fine. Also while testing the following code, i noticed that if we reduce the height beyond a limit the footer actually comes above the header. Although, practically the height would never be so less, but still you might want to add z-index:5000 to header tag

Comment: & Code Burn... can you post up the solution for this? I'm interested in seeing the code :)

Comment: Kit has already posted the code, you just need to remove the height:100% from sections div.

Answer (score 4):

Like this?

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Test</title>
    <style type="text/css">

    html, body, h1 {
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
    }

    header, nav, article, section, footer, address {  
        display: block;  
    }

    header {
        position:relative;
        height: 50px;
        width: 100%;
        background-color:#2b2b2b;
    }

    footer{
        height: 50px; 
        width:100%; 
        bottom: 0px; 
        position: fixed; 
        background: red;
        border-top: 5px solid yellow;
    }

    #explorer{
        position:relative; bottom:55px; 
    }

    #sections{
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        bottom: 55px;
        position:fixed;
        top: 50px;
        background: rgba(0,0,256,.5);
    }

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <header >
        <h1>Test</h1>
    </header>
    <div id="explorer" >
        <div id="sections" >
        &nbsp;
        </div>
    </div>
    <footer>
        /* Footer Content */
    </footer>
</body>
```

Comment: No, the blue area must end before the footer.