# Resizable chart

Tags: css, jqplot

I have a bar chart (jqplot). How do I make it fill out the entire screen regardless of screen resolution? Like this one: https://www.desmos.com/calculator . It automatically resizes the chart when the window is changed.

Comment: Do you have any code? It's kinda hard to answer a code related problem without seeing some code..

Comment: take a look a this: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5047735/how-to-resize-content-area-with-css-dynamically-and-no-javascript][1]
 you might find a clue at your problem.

  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5047735/how-to-resize-content-area-with-css-dynamically-and-no-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me was this (adapted from http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/area.html):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>    
    <title>Filled (Area) Charts</title>

    <script class="include" type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script class="include" type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.jqplot.min.js"></script>
    <script class="include" type="text/javascript" src="../plugins/jqplot.categoryAxisRenderer.min.js"></script>

    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
            var l2 = [11, 9, 5, 12, 14];
            var l3 = [4, 8, 5, 3, 6];
            var l4 = [12, 6, 13, 11, 2]; 

            var plot = $.jqplot('chart1b',[l2, l3, l4],{
               stackSeries: true,
               showMarker: false,
               seriesDefaults: {
                   fill: true
               },
               axes: {
                   xaxis: {
                       renderer: $.jqplot.CategoryAxisRenderer,
                       ticks: ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thr", "Fri"]
                   }
               }
            });

            resizePlot(plot);

            $(window).bind('resize', function(event, ui) {
                resizePlot(plot);
            });
        });

        function resizePlot($plot) {
            $($plot.targetId).height($(window).height() * 0.75);
            $plot.replot( { resetAxes: true } );
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="example-content">
        <div id="chart1b"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The key is to bind a handler to the `resize` event of the `window`. With this you can get the size of the window and in turn modify the height of the plot container. We need to modify the height this way because the `resize` event only seemed to affect the width of the plot.

My example here sets the plot to be 75% of the height of the window - you will need to adjust this to suit your requirements.

Comment: Thx for answear! A minor issue though. It works perfectly in IE and Firefox. But when the window is maximised or minimised in Chrome, the chart goes blank. When a refresh is made the chart is back. Any ideas how to solve this?

Comment: Glad to help. I'm not sure what to do about the Chrome issue - I can't repro it at my end. The only thing I can think of is to make sure you have the most recent version of jqplot. Does this problem occur just with the code I posted above or have you included it in a larger work?

Comment: I tried it with yours and mine. Also with a demo at jqplot webpage itself. All failed with Chrome. Must have something to do with a recent update of chrome.